# Customizing Method Not Allowed, 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a rest api and often use  `Model::findOrFail(id)`, so I made the following exception handler if nothing is found:

```
if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Record not found',
            ], 404);
        }
```

But this way, I can't see which record is not found.. is there a way for me to include the model object it was searching for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `ModelNotFoundException` has methods to determine model and ids.
Check these:

```
$exception->getModel(); 
$exception->getIds();
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/ModelNotFoundException.html